# App Store Expedite Criteria

Tags: ios, app-store

We submitted an app to the App Store after 2 months of testing and found that if a Facebook profile does not have a current location value, that the information returned from Facebook is null not blank (just something we never tested as all of our testers had locations entered - just a miss on our part).

This is causing our application to CRASH upon login.  We submitted a 2.0.1 version that fixed this with an expedite request and we received this from Apple ????  (My question is.. what does the criteria for expediting a review if its not to fix a login crash of your app?)

From Apple: (and of course from do_not_reply@apple.com) so I can't ask them.

> Thank you for contacting us requesting an expedited review for your
>   app, Slimgage.
>
> While we do our best to accommodate requests for expedited reviews,
>   unfortunately we cannot grant your request at this time as it does not
>   meet the criteria for expediting a review.
>
> Helping you get your app or update onto the App Store is very
>   important to us, and we are working hard to process all submissions as
>   quickly as possible. We thank you for your understanding.
>
> Best Regards,
>
> App Review Team

Comment: This is like the "too minor" category for rejected edits. </meta>

Comment: I feel for you, but is this really a question for SO? In fact, is it a question? To me it seems more like a complaint. Apple's process is opaque, so no one can really answer it. I've had a review expedited, but it was because there was an event coming up that I needed to get to with my app.

Comment: it's clearly a question and he's clearly looking for guidance, not complaint. I am looking into app store / b2b process for an application and am trying very hard to find this information out BEFORE we ever need to use it. it's quite scary that you cannot release a critical fix quickly unless apple want to. I would have posted here as this community is generally very helpful and as you say there is little information around to help when your back is against the wall

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While this is a rotten place to be, from Apple's point of view, this isn't critical. If your update fixed an issue that was causing user data loss, then they might accept the expedited review. But a simple crash for some users isn't critical to them. I know it is to you and users. But if Apple granted an expedited review for every update that simply fixed a crash then there  would be nothing but expedited reviews.

Answer (score 9):

The expedited reviews is a process based on a queue, just like the standard review. However, you can move “up” the queue with the reason you provide for expedite, or if your app is currently being promoted at the App Store.

e.g. if you just “need it fast” and don’t have a real issue/bug to fix you may be less important to review at the moment.

however, there are some ways you can perhaps skip the process completely, or at least not be in the stress of time constraints your app is being damaged. You can use [rollout.io](https://rollout.io) for this - an SDK which allows you to solve quality issues in production instantly, and is fully compliant with Apple's guidelines. (Disclaimer: I'm on of the team on Rollout.io)

You’ll be able to contain the issue, and not wait around for the expedited review to happen.

hope this helps!
Eido, 
Rollout.io

P.S This site shows the average approval time on Apple's app store (regular submitting process) - http://appreviewtimes.com/